# how to export data from table to excel on SQL Server 2008 with T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008, excel, t-sql

Want to export data from a table in SQL Server 2008 to a excel file on windows 7 with T-SQL. 
By searching over internet, many try following:

```
Insert into openrowset ('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Excel 8.0;Database=c:\MyExcel.xls;','SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
select * FROM mytab
```

I tried it too. I it is not working.

Also try below:

```
sqlcmd -S myServer -d myDB -E -Q "select * from Tab" -o "MyData.csv" -h-1 -s","
```

okay with no error, but no file created. Also not sure if this can be run in T-SQL.

Any better solution for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use export wizard to create a SSIS package. Select [First row is column name], excel destination, your source table or query
2. In the last step, save SSIS package as file
3. Use sp_configure to enable xp_cmdshell
4. use t-sql script to  exec ('dtexec /file: ')

Answer (score 0):

Bulk Copy Program = bcp

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

example usage:

```
bcp AdventureWorks2012.Sales.Currency out "Currency Types.dat" -T -c
```

This is a command line util so you will need to use the command shell functionality if you have to do this from SQL Server.  I am curious if the sqlcmd you were using was trying to use bcp under the hood potentially.  Be aware creating files directly from SQL you will have permission issues if you are sending out to certain locations as the SQL Account may not have access.  And above all remember that the machine running the TSQL is not the server, so where it saves to when using a local path is relative to the server running the script, NOT the user running the script over TCP/IP to SQL Server.  I think the default for file creation for SQL server is the root install of the 'data' location of SQL Server on the Server.  Something like:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\(version current is: 110)\Data
```

Comment: Thanks. How to run it in TSQL, not in OS command line window?

Comment: Enable XP_Cmdshell in config options.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190693.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Got xp_cmdshell working with bcp. but there is problem: no header(column name) can be generated with bcp.

Comment: You can I believe add a format file as well to it that could include headers.  With all the work you are doing it may be easier to do just do a .NET StreamWriter with ADO.NET and import a library in as a CLR, then call that.  I have never done this but I saw you knew C# so this may be an option.  I have never done this and I do most of my file creation through .NET directly with Linq but if you need this to work in SQL as a must have this may be a viable alternative for you.

Comment: Dont understand why you have to do it in T-SQL. You have already accept to use BCP utility and xp_cmdshell, it is already not just T-SQL. Comparing with BCP, you can create a simple SSIS package which can configured to have header(column name) automatically in your target excel file, and you can also configure dynamic destination to give whatever file name you need each time when you run. If you have to run it in T-sql, then you can also use xp_cmdshell to run DTEXEC